# How to install node-win-shortcut by using npm

Tags: node.js, npm, electron, npm-install

I am trying to add native Windows notifications to Zulip Electron using the `electron-windows-notifications` module.

So I was reading the sample code given at `https://github.com/felixrieseberg/electron-windows-notifications/blob/master/samples/shortcut.js` which creates a shortcut for the app, and is a required for notifications to work.

The code is given below as well:

```
const shortcut = require('node-win-shortcut')
const appId = 'electron-windows-notifications'

shortcut.createShortcut(process.execPath, 'node', appId)
```

I ran `npm install node-win-shortcut` to install the package. However, when I add `const shortcut = require('node-win-shortcut');` to my file, VS Code shows the error:

`Could not find a declaration file for module 'node-win-shortcut'. '.../zulip-electron/node_modules/node-win-shortcut/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
  Try 'npm install @types/node-win-shortcut' if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing 'declare module 'node-win-shortcut'';`

This is indeed correct as `node-win-shortcut/index.js` just has:

`module.exports = require('./build/Release/node_win_shortcut_bindings.node');`

I don't know how to access the `createShortcut()` method. I suspect that my install of `node-win-shortcut` is not fully complete, and some build process still remains.

Comment: Can you please show code ? For shortcut you should use squirrel .

Comment: Adding the whole file may not be relevant here.

Comment: This seems like a Typescript related issue. Does @types/node-win-shortcut exist?

Comment: @SeanKelly No it does not exist. I tried installing and it said package not found.

Comment: @SwapnilRustagi your constant where you are requiring the package should be a variable. (i.e. var shortcut = (require 'node_win_shortcut'); Try that!

Comment: @RachelGallen I will try that. However what is the reason for that?

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you are using TypeScript. When you want to use JS libraries from TypeScript (using strict checks like [`noImplicitAny`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html)), you have to have the type declarations for the modules you want to use. The [DefinitelyTyped](https://definitelytyped.org/) project on [GitHub](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped) provides type declaration files for NPM packages that don't on their own and they are published under the [@types organization](https://www.npmjs.com/~types) on NPM. If a package doesn't ship with type definitions, you can look it up [here](https://microsoft.github.io/TypeSearch/) to find out whether there is a package with them.

The package you need, however, seem to not be covered. What you can do is write your own type definitions so that you can use this library in TypeScript. A minimal type declaration that would cover just the method you need would look like the following:

```
declare module 'node-win-shortcut' {
  function createShortcut(path: String, name: String, appId: String): void
}
```

If you put this type declaration in a file (i.e. `node-win-shorcut.d.ts`) and import it where you need you should be good to go.

If for any reason this is not working, you can use DefinitelyTyped type declarations as a reference for you to model your own, like [this very simple one](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/types/is-number) for the [`is-number`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/is-number) package.

---

As a separate note, the reason why you don't see the method itself in the JavaScript code is that the bindings are actually [built on installation](https://github.com/nadavbar/node-win-shortcut/blob/master/package.json#L20) from the native code [you can see here](https://github.com/nadavbar/node-win-shortcut/blob/master/node_win_shortcut_bindings.cc#L113-L143) (as you can imagine, creating a shortcut on Windows require native code bindings that has to be run on a Windows system -- `npm i node-win-shorcut` would fail on Linux or MacOS). You can have a look in the `node_modules/node-win-shortcut` directory to see the built artifact in the file referenced from the `index.js` file.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation. I will try it as soon as I can.